# Spring Hibernate JPA Bidirectional OneToOne - not updating id on delete

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I have 2 entities in a OneToOne relationship:

A User entity :

```
@Entity
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn()
    private StudentInfo studentInfo;
}
```

And a StudentInfo entity:

```
@Entity
public class StudentInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn()
    private User user;
}
```

When I delete the first StudentInfo instance from the database (with id=1) using  `studentRepository.deleteById((long) 1)` ; , the instance does get deleted, so does the User associated with it, but the problem is that the ids of the other objects in the database don't get updated.

After deleted a student, the users in the database look like this :

[image: Users after delete]

And the students remaining (only one):

[image: Students after delete]

How can I make so that the ids are automatically updated on delete ?

(2, 3, 4) -> (1, 2, 3).

Comment: *the problem is that the ids of the other objects in the database don't get updated.* I have no idea why you would expect such a thing to happen.

Comment: @AlanHay I looked into it too. Indeed I should not have expected this to happed. Thank you for your time ! Also: I'm new and I don't know how to close this question

Comment: No need to close the question. While the answer is obvious for experienced users it is still a valid question. Post your own answer containing what you learned and accept it (I think you'll have to wait 3 days or something).

Comment: @JensSchauder thank you for the tip. I did just that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is quite a dumb question because while the ids in a database do have to be unique for each line in a table, they don't have to be consecutive.

As such, when a registry (a line) in a database table is deleted, the other registries's ids don't get updated because there is  no need for it. This is true for all sql databases and has nothing to do with Spring or JPA.